# How to properly test ngForm reset? (reset with default value)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-forms

I have this ngForm with contans among other things a textfield for a message.
This textfield should be prefilled with a previously chosen signature (Best regards, ...).

Also, there is a reset button which triggers following method:

```
reset() {
    this.form.resetForm( {message: this.getDefaultMessage()});
}
```

This resets every formfield and sets the default for the message field with following method:

```
getDefaultMessage() {
    if (this.user.signature) {
      return '\n\n' + this.user.signature;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
}
```

While testing the running application this works like a charm, but I'm struggling to test this successfully.

```
it('should reset form', () => {
    const signature = 'Best regards';                                  
    component.user.signature = signature;                               // setting user signature
    component.reset();                                                  // trigger reset
    expect(component.user.signature).toEqual(signature);               // user signature successfully set
    expect(component.getDefaultMessage()).toContain(signatur);          // default message contains specified signature
    expect(component.message).toEqual(component.getDefaultMessage());   // (FAILING) message field was set to the result of the getDefaultMessage-method 
});
```

The last expect block generates this error:

```
1) should reset form
     MaUploadComponent
     Expected '' to equal '

Best Regards'.
```

My best guess is, that the resetForm-method of ngForm is run at a specific point in the component-refresh-lifecycle, specically the injeciton of given default values because testing the reset fields without default is working without any problems.

But how do i test this properly?
Thanks in advance!